# Why the inline style does not work?

Tags: css

I have this code that works fine with the css :

```
  .fancy_image img {
    width: <?=$width;?>px;
    height: <?=$height;?>px;
  }

<div class='fancy_image'>
    <a href="<?=$content;?>" rel="prettyPhoto[mixed]">
      <img class='fade' src="<?=$content;?>" alt='' />
    </a>    
</div>
```

This works as expected, but when i remove the .fancy_image img css style and set the img as :

```
<img class='fade' src="<?=$content;?>" width="<?=$width;?>px" height="<?=$height;?>px" alt='' />
```

It shows a different result (the image is actually the correct size, but the div frame occupies 100% of the page width.

Any idea why this could be happening ?

EDIT: I think i may found the reason just now. I have :

```
.fade {
    background: url('images/hover.png');
}
```

which is responsible for that(works if it's removed). I will be trying to fix it. It seems that this background image causes the stretch.

Comment: Which other languages are going on here?

Comment: it's along with php, you can safely ignore that. Width and Height are correctly specified for sure in both examples.

Comment: @Ocus : my ignorant friend, the echo shortcut is very powerful if you happen to know how to use templates in php and don't just throw echoes everywhere in your code :P

Comment: @mation : Still does not work.

Comment: Well, the image_properties div can just be omitted. I will edit the post to reflect that, that div does not affect it at all.

Comment: It seems to be the .fade class, edited my question

Comment: Why do you expect `<div class='fancy_image'>` to be anything other than `display:block` (i.e. full width)? A simple demo would clear everything up and probably get you an answer right away.

Comment: Interesting problem, i have to find a way to instruct the background hover image to occupy the same width, but i have to do it from the php file, because width and height are parameters.

Comment: @muistooshort: Please recheck my question, i think it makes full sense now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the value in width and height attributes without "px".

Comment: check using inline style instead of width, height attributes. <img class='fade' src="<?=$content;?>" style="width:<?=$width?>px;height:<?=$height;?>px" alt='' />

Comment: According to this, you should not use "px", you just put the int value  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_width.asp

Comment: k, changed it, did not affect anyway, i guess the browser recognizes the px

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you can use it.

```
<img class='fade' src="<?=$content;?>" style="width:<?=$width?>px;height:<?=$height;?>px" alt='' />
```

For the attribute you cant use unit like ***px***

```
<img class='fade' src="<?=$content;?>" width="<?=$width;?>px" height="<?=$height;?>px" alt='' />
```

Comment: @SpyrosP Hope this cud helpful.

Comment: But this is exactly what i do and does not work :P Please read the question.

Comment: @SpyrosP Sorry, I did a mistake, please have a look at now. :)

Comment: It's not a problem with px, it's a problem with the .fade class as i mention in my question.

Comment: @SpyrosP Gr8, I set my favorite and removed your minus also, because it is good leaning point. :)